# Extracting, modelling and changing data model, with mongoid/mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, database

I'm looking for a better way, if it's possible, for manipulating an existing mondodb datamodel using amazing [mongoid ODM](http://mongoid.org/) driver.

Suppose you have an [embedded one to many](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html) data model like the following :

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :nickname
  embeds_many :watchlists
end

class Watchlist
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :html_url
 field :description
 field :tags_array, type: Array
 embedded_in :user
end
```

Now, for all **users** you want to extract just a part of every **watchlist**, if and only if, it has

```
tags_array == ["ruby", "web", "framework"]
```

having back just few fields (not the entire watchlist doc):

1. watchlist's html_url content
2. watchlist's description content

and

1. related parent nickname ( User.nickname )

I tried something like this :

```
1.9.2p290 :574 > Competitor = Struct.new(:html_url, :description, :user)
=> #<Class:0xed08de8>
1.9.2p290 :575 > competitors = []
=> []
1.9.2p290 :576 >  User.all.map do |user|
1.9.2p290 :577 >     user.watchlists.all.map do |wl|
1.9.2p290 :578 >           if wl.tags_array == ["ruby", "web", "framework"]
1.9.2p290 :579?>                 competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.user.nickname)
1.9.2p290 :580?>           end
1.9.2p290 :581?>     end
1.9.2p290 :582?> end
```

here are some resoults :

```
1.9.2p290 :585 > competitors
=> [#<struct html_url="https://github.com/rails/rails", description="Ruby on Rails", user="lgs">, #<struct html_url="https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra", description="Classy web-development dressed in a DSL (official / canonical repo)", user="lgs">]
1.9.2p290 :586 > competitors.size
=> 2
1.9.2p290 :599 > competitors[0][:html_url]
=> "https://github.com/rails/rails"
1.9.2p290 :600 > competitors[1][:html_url]
=> "https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra"
1.9.2p290 :601 >
```

But I wonder, if there are better, smarter, faster, efficient, effective, aesthetic ( or just **"different"** ) way, of doing that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do two things:

- Filter the users with db query instead of filtering in application
- only fetch fields you need from db, rather than the whole user objects(assuming you have some other stuff in user, which you omitted here for brevity)

  ```
  Competitor = Struct.new(:html_url, :description, :user)
  competitors = []
  User.where('watchlists.tags_array' => %w[ruby web framework]).
      only(:nickname, :watchlists).each do |u|
    u.watchlists.where(:tags_array => %w[ruby web framework]).each do |wl|
      competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, u.nickname)
    end
  end
  ```

PS: Probably you do not want to use `map` on `User.all`, it will require a lot of memory if you have lots of heavy user documents. Also, you are not using the mapped users, but instead collecting results in the `competitors` array yourself, so `each` should work just fine.

Comment: Hey, I tried a benchmark comparison between our to code solutions and your one appear to be really faster and less CPU consuming, thats great. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123990/how-to-benchmarking-mongodb-mongoid-scripts-for-comparing-two-different-query-t?answertab=oldest#tab-top